# Select filter terms along with their counts

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables:

table `Filters`

```
id   INT(11) PRIMARY KEY
text VARCHAR(50)
```

table `items`

```
id    INT(11) PRIMARY KEY
title VARCHAR(255)
```

I'd like to dipslay all filter terms along with count fo their occurence among titles

I'm currently using this statement but I get zeroes as counts

```
SELECT  filters.text, 
        (SELECT COUNT(items.id) 
         FROM items 
         WHERE (items.title LIKE 'filters.text' OR 
                items.title LIKE '%filters.text' OR 
                items.title LIKE '%filters.text%' OR 
                items.title LIKE 'filters.text%')
        ) AS count
        FROM filters, items
GROUP BY filters.ID
ORDER BY filters.ID DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give this a try,

```
SELECT  a.text, COUNT(b.id) totalCount
FROM    filters a
        LEFT JOIN items b
            ON b.title LIKE CONCAT('%',a.text,'%')
GROUP BY a.text
ORDER BY totalCount DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2ad8/1)